# How to retrieve state without persisting it with Lagom Framework

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, lagom

I'm learning to use Lagom Framework and I can't reach understanding of how the persistent side works.

My example is simple : I have a product stock and several services that create, purchase and order products, making the stock fluctuate. At the moment, I persist product with stock quantity along with each stock movement with amount added/removed. What I would like to achieve is to only persist all stock movements and create a product from them.

My understanding of Lagom Framework is that I should not persist products, but instead events of stock movements. That way, if I want to know the stock of a product, the events are processed somehow to retrieve the current state.

In my Service implementation, here is how I get a product state for now :

```
@Override
public ServiceCall<String, NotUsed, Source<Product, ?>> getProduct() {
    return (id, req) -> {
        Source<Product, ?> result = session.select("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?", id)
                .map(row -> new Product(row.getString("id"), row.getString("ean"), row.getLong("quantity")));
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);
    };
}
```

and here is how I add a stock :

```
@Override
public ServiceCall<String, Stock, NotUsed> add() {
    return (id, request) -> {
        log.info("EAN: {}. Supply order received.", id);
        PersistentEntityRef<StockCommand> ref = persistentEntityRegistry.refFor(StockEntity.class, id);
        return ref.ask(new StockCommand.AddStock(request.amount)).thenApply(r -> NotUsed.getInstance());
    };
}
```

Is there a way with Lagom to reconstruct the product state only with persisted events ? How can it be achieved for my needs ?

Answer (score 2):

My apologies, I find your example very confusing. So you have Inventory with multiple products. Each product has a count (which represents how many items are available). Order processes decrement the count as product get purchased, warehouse delivery processes increment the stock (therefore the count).

You can use the `state()` function in the command to get the state.

See https://github.com/orefalo/lagom-sample-bank for more details on a similar use case.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I'm sorry to have forgotten to check this question. This has been solved by completely refactoring the project, making my question now irrelevant. Thank you for trying to help though.